# How to analyse File Upload/ Download in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am doing load testing for file upload and download scenarios in JMeter.

I would like to know, which listeners can be used for such purpose and how to analyse the reports?

Any link on analysis of reports will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on how your target system deals with this process.

I would imagine you would need:

- [Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) or the [Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) to perform web authorization;
- [JSONExtractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor/) to extract some data from the response;
- [Assertions](http://thatsabug.com/2019/06/28/jmeter_3.html) to fail requests that do not fulfill some requirement (upload and download time, e.g.)

Investigating the download content itself is a bit out-of-scope of JMeter components - you can deal with it by running generic code using [BeanShells](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell/).

Answer (score 0):

The funny thing is that [you should not be using any Listeners](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing/). Listeners don't add any value, they're useful only for tests development and/or debugging.

According to [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) you should [run your test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) with all Listeners disabled or better removed like:

```
jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl -e -o /path/to/report/folder
```

When your test script finishes JMeter will generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) which can be used for results analysis.